# Getting Error: unrecognized option -march=nocona while installing aerospike 3.10.0 version for python on amazon linux 2 system

Tags: python-3.x, arm64, aerospike, amazon-linux-2

I am currently using aerospike version < 4.9, which requires a python aerospike client < 5.0.0

While doing pip install aerospike==3.10.0, I am getting this error

```
  Assembler messages:
  Error: unknown architecture `nocona'
  
  Error: unrecognized option -march=nocona
  cc1: error: unknown value ‘nocona’ for -march
  error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> aerospike

pip install aerospike works well, as it installs python aerospike client version 10.0.0 (latest version)

I have tried changing the setup.py file from the github repo.
https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-python/blob/3.10.0/setup.py

But then the issue changes to incompatibility between i386:x86-64 architecture of input file `./aerospike-client-c/lib/libaerospike.a(ltm.o)' and aarch64 output.

Answer (score 2):

ARM support wasn't added until [Aerospike Client Library version 8.0.0](https://download.aerospike.com/download/client/python/notes.html#8.0.0).

Comment: Is there any workaround for this issue? Presently, I can't update my aerospike to 4.9 and above.

Comment: Use x86 instances instead of graviton instances (graviton instances have a 'g' in their name) until you are on a version with ARM support.